# How to change Python sys.path for prevent Permission Denied occurs when pip install Python packages which pointing to wrong directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv

I've been trying to install Python packages (using virtualenvironment) with pip install.

However, it's pointing to wrong directory which cause permission denied.

```
creating /mnt/hadoop/apm_alert/seq_pipeline/env3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nmap
    error: could not create '/mnt/hadoop/apm_alert/seq_pipeline/env3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nmap': Permission denied
```

I expected it to use ***'/mnt/hadoop/rundeck/api/env3/lib/python3.6/site-packages'*** which is exists in sys.path

```
(env3) [banthita_lim@local ~]$ python -m site
sys.path = [
    '/home/banthita_lim',
    '/mnt/hadoop/rundeck/api/env3/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
    '/usr/lib64/python36.zip',
    '/usr/lib64/python3.6',
    '/usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload',
    '/mnt/hadoop/apm_alert/seq_pipeline/env3/lib64/python3.6/site-packages',
    '/mnt/hadoop/apm_alert/seq_pipeline/env3/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/home/banthita_lim/.local' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/home/banthita_lim/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages' (exists)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: False
```

location of env

```
[banthita_lim@local ~]$ cd /mnt/hadoop/rundeck/api/
[banthita_lim@local api]$ ll
total 56
drwxrwxr-x 2 banthita_lim banthita_lim 4096 Dec 10 12:56 __pycache__
-rw-rw-r-- 1 banthita_lim banthita_lim  227 Dec 10 10:02 config.py
drwxrwxr-x 5 banthita_lim banthita_lim 4096 Dec 10 13:49 env3
```

Python site-packages

```
[banthita_lim@local site-packages]$ pwd
/mnt/hadoop/rundeck/api/env3/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

So, how can I install the package inside the desired directory ?

Thanks